# can't create new custom profile with installation

Tags: package

I am adding custom profile in the package, however when installing the custom profile is not created in my org. After more investigating, if I created the custom profile before the installation the package can update the fls and permissions.

Is there is no way creating a custom profile on package installation? If so can I do that with an installation script?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you take a look at Permission Sets, unlike Profiles, they are physically installed into the subscriber org, upgradable and thus more useful to your users as a result. You typically describe them in respect to the features and functions of your package rather than the roles/profiles you think your users fit into when using your package. http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/perm_sets_overview.htm

Comment: There is also a good write up about profiles vs permission sets in the ISV Force guide (cannot recommend this document enough), http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Profiles cannot be created automatically by installing. If you set up some profile setting then its settings will be applied to existing matching profiles on target Organisation. You have to manually create that profile before/after installation. But you can setup permission sets by installing.